# can I use the same spark context to write different files using actors?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, akka, hdfs

I have a requirement where I am trying to basically read directories from google storage and trying to write them to my hdfs. I currently created an actor system and passed the spark context to each of the actors being spawned. The only problem is that the reads and writes were still happening sequentially. Is there anyway to work around this?

**edit:**

I am basically trying to bring

gs://bucket/file1 to hdfs://file1

and

gs://bucket/file2 to hdfs://file2

both files to be brought to the in parallel using actors. Actor1 copies file 1 and Actor2 copies file 2.

Comment: This question is quite broad to answer. Neverthess, the first thing I think about when you describe your problem is "available resources". If you are using the same SparkContext, parallelized actions would occur when resources are available.

Comment: I think resources should be available because each write job spawns up one stage of 10 tasks each. I have a 200 core cluster with 196 cores being used by the executors. So I am guessing that 10 tasks will involve only 10 cores.

Comment: Is Akka necessary? I think if you parallelize a collection with references to each file, and then run the copy inside a future you might be ok.

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, but it may work.